# VLC loop/repeat not seamless when running in remote command mode

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc, raspberry-pi4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian and run VLC from a command prompt with the following parameters

`vlc --intf rc --rc-host localhost:65513 --fullscreen`

I have successfully gotten VLC to play a video by issuing remote commands through a Socket and have issued a repeat/loop command.

The looping doesn't have to be seamless but it momentarily cuts back to the command prompt before it replays the video and looks unprofessional.

Is there any solution to this? I cannot find anything that works. I can live with the screen staying black for a moment but can't have work presentations playing continously on a screen that shows Linux in the background every 30 seconds.

Comment: Unless you can add a more programming-centric slant on your question, it doesn't seem to be very [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and should probably be asked on e.g. [Super User](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I am writing a service in C# Net core but that seems silly to mention just so it can be seen as a programming problem. We have tags for VLC here so why can't I ask this question without being jumped on?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this topic yet @Adam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same happened to me some month ago, it looks that the only one solution is to wait for the release of vlc 4.0 for raspbian too, and no plans about it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, here is how I "fixed it" :

1. set desktop background to a black jpeg.
2. Told the panel not to appear at launch by editing ***/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart*** as follow (first line that launchs the panel is commented to do so) :

```
    #@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
    @pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
    @xscreensaver -no -splash
```

3. Prevent the pi to blank screen or go to sleep by editing file ***/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf*** and adding in the **[SeatDefaults]** section :

```
    xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms
```

Now when VLC is looping, it still cuts back to the desktop but as everything is blacked out (no panel, black background), the cut becomes invisible.

Et voilà :)
My best.
S.Y.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using two instances of VLC, whereby one instance streams the video to the other using the `--sout-keep` flag. This way the VLC instance actually producing an image shows a continuous stream, as the streaming instance tries to keep one stream instance open across multiple(or one looped) file.

For example:

```
vlc rtp://127.0.0.1 --intf dummy --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --alsa-audio-device hw:1,0 &
cvlc file.mp4 --sout "#rtp{mux=ts,dst=127.0.0.1,sdp=sap,name='somename'}" --sout-keep --loop
```